# What is the PS3 Root key/what does it do/how is it used?

Tags: key, root, playstation3

I have been reading about this Sony vs GeoHot case. I however don't understand what this root key is (I program mainly on windows, linux is blank to me).

Comment: Do you know anything about encryption?

Comment: Yes, symmetric encryption I believe has something to do with this

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask such a question, but since you have ... the concept is similar to digital signatures.  A 'digital signature' is created for an application using this root key, and its validity is checked on the console before execution is allowed.  Having the root key allows people to create their own application signatures, thereby allowing 3rd party code to run on the PS3, once a valid signature is generated for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jeff Parker

> The concept is similar to digital signatures. A 'digital
> signature' is created for an application using this root key, and its
> validity is checked on the console before execution is allowed. Having
> the root key allows people to create their own application signatures,
> thereby allowing 3rd party code to run on the PS3, once a valid
> signature is generated for it.